# Obtener un valor especifico de un JSON obtenido desde una función request (node js)

Tags: javascript

Hola bueno estoy haciendo pruebas con una api pido el json me devuelve esto:

```
{
  "responseId": "-----",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "como estas",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Estoy bien!",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Estoy bien!"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/prueba/agent/intents/---",
      "displayName": "Que tal esta?"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "es"
  }
}
```

Bueno creo que esto es un json y quiero el valor fulfillmentText:
he visto y investigado que tengo que hacer esto

```
var texto = json
var obj = JSON.parse(texto);
console.log(obj.fulfillmentText o obj["fulfillmentText"])
me devuelve undefined
```

¿Como hago que me devuelva el valor fulfillmentText?

Comment: tu ruta esta mal es: `obj. queryResult. fulfillmentText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te fijas, la clave 'fullfillmentText' está anidada dentro de un objeto 'queryResult', por lo que la forma de acceder debe incluir la ruta completa: 
`console.log(obj.queryResult.fullfillmentText)`

Para acceder a text: "Estoy bien!", sería:
`console.log(json.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0])`

Comment: ya pero cuando lo paso por el JSON.parse me quita esas dos de text y me deja el texto.

Comment: Pues no debería, ya que JSON.parse simplemente transforma el JSON en un objeto javascript.

En este ejemplo funciona correctamente, mostrando el texto "Estoy bien!" en el log:

var JSONparseado = JSON.parse(objetoJSON); 

console.log(JSONparseado.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0]);

Comment: raro ya que me devuelvo esto:
{
  responseId: '`------',
  queryResult: {
    queryText: 'hola',
    parameters: {},
    allRequiredParamsPresent: true,
    fulfillmentText: 'Hola',
    fulfillmentMessages: [ [Object] ],
    intent: {
      name: 'projects/prueba/agent/intents/',
      displayName: '-'
    },
    intentDetectionConfidence: 1,
    languageCode: 'es'
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de ver la solución ya que la string que quiero esta dentro de un objeto simplemente tengo que especificarlo es decir asi:

```
var texto = json;
var obj = JSON.parse(texto)
console.log(obj.queryResult.fulfillmentText);
```

Answer (score 0):

La función JSON.parse te devuelve un objeto a partir de una cadena de texto con formato JSON.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse

Comprueba que tu variable *texto* sea una cadena de texto.

Esto funciona:

```
var response = '{"fulfillmentText": "Estoy ben!"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(obj.fulfillmentText); // devuelve: Estoy ben!
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, lo que encuentras dentro del Array "fulfillmentMessages" es un Object (y dentro de este hay otro). El siguiente código ejecuta perfectamente, de 2 formas diferentes:

```js
function leer(){

 var objetoJSON = {
  "responseId": "-----",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "como estas",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Estoy bien!",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Estoy bien!"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/prueba/agent/intents/---",
      "displayName": "Que tal esta?"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "es"
  }
}

var stringJSON = JSON.stringify(objetoJSON); //Objeto Javascript pasado a JSON

var JSONparseado = JSON.parse(stringJSON); //JSON parseado a objeto Javascript

//Accedemos a la propiedad texto anidada
  console.log(JSONparseado.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0]);
//También funciona de este modo
  console.log(JSONparseado["queryResult"]["fulfillmentMessages"][0]["text"]["text"][0]);

//Log del JSON completo
  console.log(JSONparseado);
}
```

[image: Console.log de Formato JSON parseado]

Te recomiendo consultar MDN para trabajar con este tipo de datos: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON